# lvalue and rvalue assignment error

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, post-increment

```
int x = 3;
int y = 5;
x++ = y;
cout << x << endl;
```

Why is the above code giving me an error, the specific error I get is

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

I am trying to review up on my C and C++. From my understanding the above code should theoretically copy over the value of `y` into `x`, then finally increment the value of `x` after the copy has finished. So it would print out "6".

Comment: Just write x = y; x++;

Comment: What has the question title to do with the contents of your question?

Comment: what would you consider a more appropriate title? Everytime I try to come up with a clever, descriptive title stack overflow yells at me

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++. These are different languages. Rules for rvalue/lvalues of operations have subtle differences between C and C++. your use of `cout` etc seems to show that you are programming in C++, removing the C tag.

Comment: @AyBayBay, Maroun Maroun has now given one. What the hell had your question to do with pointers? no pointers in sight.

Comment: yeah I am not sure why I put up pointers, sorry about that

Comment: @Spook How about `x = y+1;`? Or would that be too readable? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow That depends on logic of that part of program. He can use either of both notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x++` results in a temporary object that has `x` value **before** the increment. And you **cannot** assign a temp object.

Examples for clarification:

```
int a=1; 
a=5; // Lvalue = Rvalue, Ok 
a=a; // Lvalue = Lvalue, Ok 
5=a; // Rvalue = Lvalue Comp. error
5=5; // Rvalue = Rvalue Comp. error
```

Comment: This is wrong, since 1 is not the l-value compiler is complaining about, it's complaining about the temporary returned before incrementing the value at `x`. This temporary will have a value of `x` before increment and not `1`.

Comment: This is also not how expressions work. `x++` is the subexpression, so it would be *almost* equivalent to `(x = x + 1) = y`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: No, `it's like writing (x = x + 1) = y;` is wrong; `x++ = y` tries to assign `y` not to `x + 1` but to the temporary with value `x`. Read my first comment properly.

Comment: @legends2k You are absolutely right. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
x++ ==> x=x+1

x++ = y ==> (x+1)=y
```

now `x+1=y` will throw `lvalue required` which means left hand side of `=` should be a variable not a constant

Comment: why is it that ++x = y works then? ++x should also map to x = x+1, I dont get it

Comment: @AyBayBay Because when you do `++x`, first `x` is incremented.. then it get some value.. then, you overwrite this value with the value of `y`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun dont you mean x gets the value of y? Arent you copying over y into x?

Comment: @AyBayBay I think you are confused with `x++` and `++x`

Comment: @AyBayBay: `++x = y` increments the value of `x` and throws it away by over-writing it with the value of `y`.

Comment: @legends2k I guess my real confusion lies in this example. In the following case: "x = y++" Y will get copied over to X and then Y's value gets incremented. I do not see why the same cant apply to "x++ = y", like its not consistent. Maybe I have just been staring at this stuff too long and I am going crazy. I thought the post-increment operator waits for all actions/assignments to happen first, and then applies the increment.

Comment: @AyBayBay try this `cout<<x++ + ++x ` and `cout<<++x + x++` then you will get it.

Comment: @AJ.; Your answer suggests that compiler will throw error for `1 = y`. I disagree. Compiler will parse it as `(x++) = y`. Now `y` has nothing to do with `1`.

Comment: @AyBayBay: This is not maths where the side doesn't matter in equality; `x = y` means `y`'s value is assigned to `x`, and not `x` assigned to `y`. The side does matter in assignment operator. The same rationale applies for your question on why there's no symmetry in `x = y++` and `x++ = y`. The post-increment does await, but in the end it returns a value and not an address, so `x = (5+1)` makes sense while `(3 + 1) = 5` doesn't.

Comment: @AyBayBay; `why is it that ++x = y works then?`: This will not work. At least in C.

Comment: @haccks: +1 Didn't know this subtle difference between C++ and C. Thanks!

Comment: This answer seems to me wrong. (8 upvotes!).

Comment: This answer is also wrong. :(

Comment: The only things missing from this answer are perhaps a couple of parens, and sequence points. Conceptually, he has nailed the specific problem (the compilation error) of the OP on the head.

Comment: @AyBayBay: ++x is an lvalue. x++ is an rvalue. This is because ++x can essentially return x, which is an lvalue, whereas x++ has to return an rvalue- the old value of x. C may not have had this nuance in it, but C++ assuredly does.

Comment: @DeadMG I think this answer is implying that it is equivalent to `x=x+1=y` and so by associativity equivalent to `x=(x+1=y)`. Sure, the fact that `x+1` gives an rvalue is the same problem, but the explanation is not really true.

Answer (score 2):

The result of the postincrement operator is a temporary object that has the value before incrementing. You may not assign a temporary object. So this statement is invalid.

```
x++ = y;
```

You could rewrite it the following way

```
( x += 1 ) = y;
```

The statement above is correct.

Comment: Isn't `( x += 1 ) = y;` modifying `x` twice without an intervening sequence point?

Comment: @legends2k I agree with you. But the problem is that the program has undefined bahaviour because operations  x = x + 1 and x = y are not sequenced.:)

Comment: @legends2k Ah, well I was referring to the *explanation* part of the answer. :D

Comment: @FredOverflow: Certainly in C++03. I'm not sure what the C++11 rules have to say about this.

Comment: @DeadMG As far as I can tell, it's not undefined in C++11. I just made a nice sequenced-before graph on paper.

Comment: Er, the left-hand-side of an assignment is sequenced-before the right-hand-side, right?

Comment: @FredOverflow It is valid code for the both Standards because operands (the left and the right) shall be calculated before calculating the result of the operator

Comment: @ DeadMG, No, it is not. The both operands shall be calculated before the assignment. So at first will be calculated x += 1 and after that ( x += 1 ) = y

Comment: @sftrabbit You are wrong. According to the C++ Standard "In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression."

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry, changed my mind again. It's valid. Haha. I drew my graph wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm not convinced it's well-defined in C++03 though. It doesn't seem to *care* about the fact that operands must be evaluated before operators. It simply states: "Between the previous
and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression." So while conceptually this would be fine in C++03, the standard says it's undefined because there's no sequence point between them.

Comment: @sftrabbit It was a standard defect. In fact in the C++ 2003 Standard there is written "In simple assignment (=), the value of the expression replaces that of the object referred to by the left operand." The C++ 2011 Standard made simply this statement more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding the above code should theoretically copy over the value of y into x, then finally increment the value of x after the copy has finished.

`x++` evaluates to an r-value (constant). Assignment operator `=` needs an l-value (variable) as its left operand.

```
x++ = y ==> (3 + 1) = 5 ==> 4 = 5
```

you can't assign a constant to a constant.  `x++ = y` is not a valid statement in either of C or C++.

Comment: `++x` is an l-value in C++, the question is tagged C++ too, fix this.

Answer (score 1):

`x++` cannot be use as left operand because it returns a value, not an address.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
x++ = y;
```

x++ is r-value, and you cannot assign to it, you can rewrite it as follows: 3 = 5; which makes no sense, you cannot assign 5 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

In your expression: `x++ = y`, `x++` is just a result of an evaluated expression so you can't assigne a value to a result.

Another think is that this expression has no meaning since the variable `x` will be updated with the value of `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `x++` is the value of `x`, but not the object `x`. The expression is a prvalue, which means you can't then assign to it (you need an lvalue).

> The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand. [ Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value — end note ] ... The result is a prvalue.

To achieve what you want, you need to do:

```
x = y;
x++;
```

In C++11, with its new sequencing rules, you could also do:

```
(x = y)++;
```

This would be undefined behaviour in C++03 because there is no sequence point between two modifications of `x`.

Comment: +1 I understand that `++x = y` is undefined since x is modified twice with no sequence point in between. Then why does C++, unlike C which prohibits both `x++ = y` and `++x = y`, allow the latter? Where does it makes sense to do `++x = y`?

Comment: @legends2k Yeah, I can't think of a reason to do it. I suppose if the operators were overloaded in some weird way, there *could* be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is this:

> From my understanding the above code should theoretically copy over
>   the value of y into x, **then** finally increment the value of x after the
>   copy has finished. So it would print out "6".

In fact, the sequencing of the increment is *undefined*. As in, it is completely undefined as to when `x` is incremented, except that it must occur before some specific times. Reading or writing `x` during this period of undefined value is undefined behaviour. That's why `x++` does not return `x` (an lvalue you can write to) but an rvalue you cannot write to- because there's simply nothing useful you can do with `x` until the time it's guaranteed to be incremented (except take the address, maybe).

You can still break this rule by referring to `x` twice- for example, consider:

```
void f(int, int);
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    f(x++, x++);
}
```

This is also undefined behaviour.